# Move/Copy files in Spark hadoop

Tags: apache-spark

I have an input folder that contains many files. I would like to do a batch operation on them like copy/move them to a new path.

I would like to do this using Spark.

Please help/suggest how to proceed on this.

Comment: Why Spark?  Why not use distcp?

Comment: Spark is really not the tool to use for normal file administration. So it might be good if you can explain whats your motivation for spark.

Comment: Whilst it's not elegant, it's a nice way for preparing for a medium side-join...

Comment: @clim How would I do it? I tried but, unsuccessfully so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257926/copying-files-from-a-hdfs-directory-to-another-with-oozie-distcp-action

Answer (score 5):

You can read it using `val myfile = sc.textFile("file://file-path")` if it is local dir and save them using  `myfile.saveAsTextFile("new-location")`. It's also possible to save with compression [Link to ScalaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@saveAsTextFile(path:String):Unit)

What spark will do is to read all files and at a same time save them to a new location and make a batch of those files and store them in new location (HDFS/local).

Make sure you have the same directory available in each worker nodes of your spark cluster

Answer (score 0):

In the upper case you have to have the local files' path on each worker node.

If you want to get rid of that you can use a distributed filesystem like hadoop filesystem (hdfs).

In this case you have to give path like this:

```
hdfs://nodename-or-ip:port/path-to-directory
```