# Copying files from a hdfs directory to another with oozie distcp-action

Tags: bash, oozie, distcp

My actions

`start_fair_usage` ends with status okey, but `test_copy` returns

```
Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.DistcpMain], main() threw exception, null
```

In `/user/comverse/data/${1}_B` I have a lot of different files, some of which I want to copy to `${NAME_NODE}/user/evkuzmin/output`. For that I try to pass `paths` from `copy_files.sh` which holds an array of paths to the files I need.

```
  <action name="start_fair_usage">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
      <job-tracker>${JOB_TRACKER}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${NAME_NODE}</name-node>
      <exec>${copy_file}</exec>      
      <argument>${today_without_dash}</argument>
      <argument>${mta}</argument>
      <!-- <file>${path}#${start_fair_usage}</file> -->
      <file>${path}${copy_file}#${copy_file}</file>
      <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="test_copy"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>

  <action name="test_copy">
    <distcp xmlns="uri:oozie:distcp-action:0.2">
      <job-tracker>${JOB_TRACKER}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${NAME_NODE}</name-node>
      <arg>${wf:actionData('start_fair_usage')['paths']}</arg>
      <!-- <arg>${NAME_NODE}/user/evkuzmin/input/*</arg> -->
      <arg>${NAME_NODE}/user/evkuzmin/output</arg>
    </distcp>
    <ok to="END"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>
```

`start_fair_usage` starts `copy_file.sh`

```
echo ${1} 
echo ${2}

dirs=(
    /user/comverse/data/${1}_B
    )
args=()

for i in $(hadoop fs -ls "${dirs[@]}" | egrep ${2}.gz | awk -F " " '{print $8}')
do
    args+=("$i")
    echo "copy file - "${i}
done

paths=${args}
echo ${paths}
```

Comment: What was the problem with DistCp?

Comment: @frank I think that `paths` which I pass to `test_copy` from `copy_file.sh` is empty. I don't know why.

Comment: I understand from the other question of yours, you want to segregate files based on date to different directories! If that is the same you are trying to achieve, why not pass the `path` directly?

Comment: @frank By directly, do you mean like the first example here [link](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_DistCpActionExtension.html)? In that example there are only one in and out paths. How would I do it with many paths? When I dont know the exact paths and number of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did in the end.

```
  <start to="start_copy"/>

  <fork name="start_copy">
    <path start="copy_mta"/>
    <path start="copy_rcr"/>
    <path start="copy_sub"/>
  </fork>

  <action name="copy_mta">
    <distcp xmlns="uri:oozie:distcp-action:0.2">
      <prepare>
        <delete path="${NAME_NODE}${dstFolder}mta/*"/>
      </prepare>
      <arg>${NAME_NODE}${srcFolder}/*mta.gz</arg>
      <arg>${NAME_NODE}${dstFolder}mta/</arg>
    </distcp>
    <ok to="end_copy"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>

  <action name="copy_rcr">
    <distcp xmlns="uri:oozie:distcp-action:0.2">
      <prepare>
        <delete path="${NAME_NODE}${dstFolder}rcr/*"/>
      </prepare>
      <arg>${NAME_NODE}${srcFolder}/*rcr.gz</arg>
      <arg>${NAME_NODE}${dstFolder}rcr/</arg>
    </distcp>
    <ok to="end_copy"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>

  <action name="copy_sub">
    <distcp xmlns="uri:oozie:distcp-action:0.2">
      <prepare>
        <delete path="${NAME_NODE}${dstFolder}sub/*"/>
      </prepare>
      <arg>${NAME_NODE}${srcFolder}/*sub.gz</arg>
      <arg>${NAME_NODE}${dstFolder}sub/</arg>
    </distcp>
    <ok to="end_copy"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>

  <join name="end_copy" to="END"/>

  <kill name="KILL">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="END"/>
```

Turned out it was possible to use wildcards in distcp, so I didn't need bash at all.

Also. Some people adviced me to write it in scala.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, FileUtil}

val conf = new Configuration()
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)

val listOfFileTypes = List("mta", "rcr", "sub")
val listOfPlatforms = List("B", "C", "H", "M", "Y")

for(fileType <- listOfFileTypes){
  FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents(new File("/apps/hive/warehouse/arstel.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin/file_" + fileType))
  for (platform <- listOfPlatforms) {
    var srcPaths = fs.globStatus(new Path("/user/comverse/data/" + "20170404" + "_" + platform + "/*" + fileType + ".gz"))
    var dstPath = new Path("/apps/hive/warehouse/arstel.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin/file_" + fileType)

    for(srcPath <- srcPaths){
      println("copying " + srcPath.getPath.toString)
      FileUtil.copy(fs, srcPath.getPath, fs, dstPath, false, conf)
    }
  }
}
```

Both things work, thought I haven't tried to run the scala script in Oozie.